How can Instagram show gallery images so fast on the post screen?
In my project that I developed with Reactnative, I am trying to show gallery images with a flatlist, using CameraRoll. However, there is a slight delay when the first load is made, and when we scroll, there is a delay while the images are loaded. As the number of images increases, the waiting time also increases.
However, on Instagram, images are loaded directly and no matter how fast we scroll, there is no lazy loading. How does Instagram do this?
export default function TestScreen() {
    const [assets, setAssets] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        prepare();
    }, []);

    prepare = async () => {
        let res = await CameraRoll.getPhotos({ first: 2000, after: null, assetType: 'All', include: ['albums'] });
        let list = [];
        if (res.edges && res.edges.length > 0) {
            res.edges.map(item => {
                let image = item.node.image;
                let galleryImage = { uri: image.uri, group: item.node.group_name };
                list.push(galleryImage);
            });
            setAssets(list);
        }
    }

    const GetItem = (item) => {
        return <Image
            key={'Key_' + item.uri}
            source={{ uri: item.uri }}
            style={{ backgroundColor: '#242424', width: '20%', height: 75, borderColor: '#ffffff', borderWidth: .5 }} />
    }

    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.playground}>
                {
                    (assets) ?
                        <FlatList
                            numColumns={5}
                            horizontal={false}
                            data={assets}
                            keyExtractor={item => 'key_' + item.uri}
                            renderItem={item => GetItem(item.item)}
                        />
                        :
                        <ActivityIndicator size="small" />
                }
            </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
}


Of course I can share code but what I want to discuss is how the approach should be. I don't expect code to be sent from the answers here anyway. For example; "When Instagram first opens, it takes the entire gallery, prepares the post screen in the background and waits" would be incredibly useful for me.

One option is to open the gallery directly using react-native-image-picker#launchImageLibrary, which eliminates the need for manual optimization. However, this approach depends on your specific needs.
In your example, since you are rendering images from the gallery, consider using react-native-image-resizer. You can specify the compressFormat as JPEG, as JPEG images are smaller in size. Additionally, you can adjust the quality setting to further optimize the image. Your prepare function will become like:
I have decreased the first from 2000 to 20 to decrease the initial loading.


import ImageResizer from 'react-native-image-resizer';

prepare = async () => {
    let res = await CameraRoll.getPhotos({ 
        first: 20, 
        after: null, 
        assetType: 'All', 
        include: ['albums'] 
    });
    let list = [];

    if (res.edges && res.edges.length > 0) {
        const resizedImagesPromises = res.edges.map(async item => {
            let image = item.node.image;
            let resizedImage = await ImageResizer.createResizedImage(
                image.uri,
                100, // New width
                100, // New height
                'JPEG', // Format
                80 // Quality
            );
            return { uri: resizedImage.uri, group: item.node.group_name };
        });

        list = await Promise.all(resizedImagesPromises);
        setAssets(list);
    }
};




Not sure how instagram does it, try using flashlist instead of flatlist, this might solve your issue.
https://github.com/Shopify/flash-list
